# Change and configure of App\User to a new directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There is lots of questions for this question. But the explanations are never complete. What steps should take to move the file App\User to App\Entities\User

I have installed a Laravel 5.2 and I have moved the default App\User (app/User.php) to folder App\Entities and therefore changing the namespace in the User.php file to namespace App\Entities; So to access the User model I have to use App\Entities\User I have also changed this setting in config\auth.php

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Entities\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

The problem most packages will not work with this new directory so I am wondering whether there are other settings that I am missing. For example I have installed the package tymondesigns/jwt-auth but now I am getting this error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 738:
Class App\User does not exist
```

The package is unable to locate the App\Entities\User and uses the default App\User I think in this file the package tries to load the User model [ vendor\tymon\src\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider.php ]

```
$this->app['Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\User\UserInterface'] = function ($app) {
    return $app['tymon.jwt.provider.user'];
};
```

The package has a config.php file but the setting isn't working either;

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Model namespace
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the full namespace to your User model.
| e.g. 'Acme\Entities\User'
|
*/

'user' => 'App\Entities\User',
```

Comment: Why are you trying to change the location of your laravel models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5 uses PSR-4 autoloader, so just move your models to another directory and change namespace in all models.

After that, run `composer dumpautoload -o` and everthing should work.

If after running the command your package will not work, try to use full namespace of `User` model in the package:

```
'user' => '\App\Entities\User',
```

Also, change namespace in `config\auth.php` (thanks @user5500750 for this):

```
'model' => App\Entities\User::class,
```

Comment: There is also a setting in config\auth.php for the user model namespace that needs to be updated as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've added this to my answer. Everything works now?